# py2exe don't install "Python version 2.5 required, which was not found in the registry"

Tags: python, py2exe

I have python 2.7 installed on my 32-bit Windows 7 machine, I'm trying to install py2exe-0.6.9 but I receive the following error

"Python version 2.5 required, which was not found in the registry", any clue how to solve this or any good alternative to convert my python solution to exe

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try pyinstaller (http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Python 2.7 version of py2exe located here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/

Note that if you are upgrading from previous versions of Python, you will likely need to modify your setup.py files to distribute some extra Microsoft DLLs as well.
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step521

Comment: Hopefully this works. I migrated to Python 2.6 a while back and it was such a pain that I've delayed the upgrade to Python 2.7.